# How to set a dynamic position for a popup?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a list of items. When I click on one of them, a popup should appear above them, but this doesn't happen, in fact the popup always appears in the same position. 
How can I change the position of the popup so that it only appears above the clicked item?

This is my CSS:

```
popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
```

Instead this is the template of my component:

```
template:'<li> <div class="popup"> <button v-on:click="aggiornaClicked"> {{ todo.name }} </button> <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup"> Acquistato! </span> </div> </li>'
```

Comment: Your css should probably refer to the class `.popup`  not the tag `popup`. I might help if you created a fiddle or inline demo with a couple of entries in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".content button").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().children(".popup").addClass("show")
});
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.content{
width:30%;
height:100px;
display:flex;
  margin-top:10px;
  background:red;
  color:white;
align-items:center;
  position:relative;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
 p{
  width:100%;
   text-align:center;
  
}
button{
  width:50%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.popup{
  opacity:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%)
}
.show.popup{
  opacity:1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <p>some text</p>
  <button>show</button>
  <div class="popup"><p>this is a popup</p></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>some text</p>
  <button>show</button>
  <div class="popup"><p>this is a popup</p></div>
</div>
```

this is similar to what you trying to do!